# Getting geodjango query to return distance as an attribute?

Tags: python, django, geospatial, geodjango

Is there a way to get a query to return the distance from the point for each location? 
Right now I have `Location.objects.filter(geometry__distance_lte=(pnt, D(mi=20)))`
but the rows don't have a distance attribute. How can I get the distance from pnt for each row that is returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and the reason was that "In order to conduct geographic queries, each geographic model requires a GeoManager model manager."

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.GeoManager

The solution would be to add `objects = models.GeoManager()` to your Location model

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Location(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = models.GeoManager()
```